# out of calibration detection and re-calibration for stereo cam

Tags: opencv, 3d, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

So, I have a stereo camera with left and right cameras that are already calibrated. Since the precision of stereo vision highly depends on the calibration, it would be useful if the system can detect whether itself is slightly out of calibration, e.g, due to temperature change or mechanical shock that changes the baseline/rotation of the two cameras slightly

So my thought is for every new image pair taken by the stereo camera, the software try to find  matching points between the two images, and recalculate the fundamental matrix to see if there is a big shift. However, finding matching points is error prone, especially when no constrains applied

My question is: since I know there should be just a slight shift of the calibration, is there a way to leverage the original calibration to enable a relaxed epipolar constrains on finding the matching points between the two images? maybe as well as a disparity constrain. e.g., I use the original calibration to calculate the distance of the feature points, and I roughly know the disparity will still be within a certain range even the calibration shifted. With such assumptions, I believe I can effectively  avoid mismatched points between left and right images, therefore ensure my new fundamental matrix calculation.

So I wonder is there a convenient way to relax the epipolar constrain by a few pixels, and also specify a `numDisparities` for feature point matching? Or maybe there is a better way to do similar things.

Comment: The cool thing with epipolar geometry is that you only have to search on a line. Relaxing this would mean searching in an area defined by an angle. I guess it would be much more error prone and time consuming.

Comment: Alternatively, why not find the most salient features in your image and try to match them directly, THEN estimating how far they lie from the epipolar line ? If you have many good features in your image you can probably do this reliably

Comment: Maybe i didnt explain well but i am trying to use the epipolor constrain to match points, but due to out of calibration, i have to relax the epipolar constain...

Comment: I understood that. I'm telling you that instead of trying to relax the epipolar constraint, you could try monitoring your matches from time to time to detect a bad calibration. It assumes that you can get a few high reliable matches without using the epipolar constraint. 

Otherwise, you could take inspiration from "A robust technique for matching two uncalibrated images through the recovery of the unknown epipolar geometry", Zhang et al, Artificial Intelligence, 2000